# Strange behavior when input is ^L

Tags: c++

Consider this C++ program compiled on Windows 10 using "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29913 for x86"

```
int main() {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << input << "\n";
}
```

If I input "^D" (produced by pressing Ctrl+D), the program prints "♦" (a diamond). If I input "^L" (produced by pressing Ctrl+L), the program produces "♀" (the female symbol). So far, so good.

Now consider this similar program:

```
int main() {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);

    cout << input << "\n";

    istringstream sin{ input };
    char token;
    sin >> token;
    cout << token << "\n";
}
```

If I input "^D" (produced by pressing Ctrl+D), the program prints "♦" (a diamond) **twice**. But if I input "^L" (produced by pressing Ctrl+L), the program produces "♀" (the female symbol) only **once**. Why?

Comment: Try to print length of `input` and see if it is really 1.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl-L` is corresponding to ASCII `12`, which is form feed. Which might clear the terminal screen.

So if the screen is cleared by printing it once, then printing it a second time wll clear the screen *again* and erase any contents previously printed.